# Protobuf-net and inheritance of immutable messages

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm trying to serialize an immutable message that has an immutable base class. However, I'm unable to convince protobuf-serializer to deserialize it to a derived type. In short this test gives me an invalid cast exception (from Base to Derived):

```
[TestFixture]
public class InheritanceTest
{
    public class Base
    {
        public int IntField { get; private set; }

        public Base(int intField)
        {
            IntField = intField;
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public string StringField { get; private set; }

        public Derived(int intField, string stringField) : base(intField)
        {
            StringField = stringField;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestInheritance()
    {
        var serializer = TypeModel.Create();
        serializer.Add(typeof (Base), true)
            .Add(1, "IntField")
            .AddSubType(2, typeof (Derived))
            .UseConstructor = false;

        serializer.Add(typeof (Derived), true)
            .Add(1, "StringField")
            .UseConstructor = false;

        serializer.CompileInPlace();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var message = new Derived(1, "Some text that is not important");

            serializer.Serialize(stream, message);
            stream.Position = 0;

            var retrieved = (Derived) serializer.Deserialize(stream, null, typeof (Derived));

            Assert.AreEqual(message.IntField, retrieved.IntField);
            Assert.AreEqual(message.StringField, retrieved.StringField);
        }
    }

}
```

This exception goes away if I convert Base and Derived to mutable types. Am I doing anything wrong or is it a limitation of protobuf-net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a side-effect of the tuple-detection, causing it to have a specific code branch. The good nes is, you should be able to fix that from your original code, simply by changing `true` to `false`. This parameter tells is whether or not to apply standard behaviours. You don't need that since you are defining the model yourself.

```
        var serializer = TypeModel.Create();
        serializer.Add(typeof (Base), false)
            .Add(1, "IntField")
            .AddSubType(2, typeof (Derived))
            .UseConstructor = false;

        serializer.Add(typeof (Derived), false)
            .Add(1, "StringField")
            .UseConstructor = false;
```

Note I haven't verified this - I will check later though.

Comment: Hi, yes - changing that to false did help. The reason they were true was because I'm actually using my own fluent interface that defines members using expressions instead of strings and I wanted to preserve standard behavior in case I'm forced to later use attributes. Accepting this answer instead as it is likely to cause less problems with inheritance (since the subtype is known for the serializer).

Comment: @VytautasMackonis Basically: it was hitting this logic: http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/automatic-serialization-whats-in-tuple.html - I will check later to see if that can be avoided in future

Answer (score 1):

```
  [TestFixture]
public class InheritanceTest
{
    public class Base
    {
        public int IntField { get; private set; }

        public Base(int intField)
        {
            IntField = intField;
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public string StringField { get; private set; }

        public Derived(int intField, string stringField) : base(intField)
        {
            StringField = stringField;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestInheritance()
    {
        var serializer = TypeModel.Create();
        serializer.Add(typeof (Base), true)
            .Add(1, "IntField")
            .UseConstructor = false;

        serializer.Add(typeof (Derived), true)
            .Add(1, "StringField")
            .UseConstructor = false;

        serializer.CompileInPlace();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var message = new Derived(1, "Some text that is not important");

            serializer.Serialize(stream, message);
            stream.Position = 0;

            var retrieved = (Derived) serializer.Deserialize(stream, null, typeof (Derived));

            Assert.AreEqual(message.IntField, retrieved.IntField);
            Assert.AreEqual(message.StringField, retrieved.StringField);
        }
    }

}
```

or

```
  [TestFixture]
    public class InheritanceTest
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class Base
        {
            [DataMember(Order = 1)]
            public int IntField { get; private set; }

            public Base(int intField)
            {
                IntField = intField;
            }
            protected Base(){}
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Derived : Base
        {
            [DataMember(Order = 3)]
            public string StringField { get; private set; }

            public Derived(int intField, string stringField) : base(intField)
            {
                StringField = stringField;
            }
            private Derived(){}
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestInheritance()
        {
            RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Base), true).AddSubType(2, typeof(Derived));

             using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var message = new Derived(1, "Some text that is not important");

                    Serializer.Serialize(stream, message);
                    stream.Position = 0;

                    var retrieved = Serializer.Deserialize<Derived>(stream);            

                    Assert.AreEqual(message.IntField, retrieved.IntField);
                    Assert.AreEqual(message.StringField, retrieved.StringField);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there no way to configure the same behavior without littering the serialized classes with attributes? Or private / protected constructors?

Comment: @VytautasMackonis you must set field numbers for every member you wish to serialise. The underlying protobuf protocol requires a unique field number for each field in a single message. See here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto for more info :)

Comment: Hi, I'm aware about the protobuf protocol. However, according to the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717500/protobuf-net-proto-file-generation-for-inheritance), the message layout only adds the derived class specific fields (in this case, StringField) to the subtype field. It does not help if I specify different numbers everywhere and re-add IntField on the derived type.

Comment: @burning_LEGION: Thanks! Although this seems counter-intuitive

Comment: @burning_LEGION just for info, you might also want to see what I wrote about tuple patterns