# Mimicing Inheritance in Protobuf-net v2

Tags: c#, ios, ios5, protobuf-net

So I have a .NET server and an IOS client and I'm trying to use protocol buffers to communicate back and forth. On the server I have one object that contains a list of FormField objects where FormField is actually going to be a subtype of FormField like say ButtonFormField.

After doing some research, I implemented my .proto files similar to this: [Protobuf-net .proto file generation for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717500/protobuf-net-proto-file-generation-for-inheritance)

Which works fine for serializing from the server to the client.

Unfortunately when I send items back to the server, I get errors because it is trying to cast FormField as ButtonFormField (which obviously doesn't work) in CompiledSerializer.cs line 49.

Does this not work in protobuf-net v2 or am I doing something wrong? I am really hoping to get this working.

**EDIT***
I tried this using protobuf-net v1 and it does work, so I'm assuming this behavior changes in v2. Is there an alternate way to do this in v2 or am I stuck on v1 for now?

**Edit 2:**
Sorry for the delay Marc. Here is a cut down .proto and the C# classes. I am using protoc to generate the IOS classes, so I am assuming generating C++ or Java with protoc as the client would generate the same effect also.

**Working Sample Proto File**

```
message PersonSelectionFormField {
}

message TextFormField {
}

message FormFieldDto {
  //Properties and optional properties truncated for brevity
  required int32 Id = 1;
  required int32 FieldTemplateId = 6;
  required int32 RowId = 9;  

  optional PersonSelectionFormField PersonSelectionFormField = 55;
  optional TextFormField TextFormField = 59;
}
```

**Classes**

```
namespace Sample.Fields
{
     //I get a list of FormFields back from the client
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(55, typeof(PersonSelectionFormField))]
    [ProtoInclude(59, typeof(TextFormField))]
    public class FormField:IFormField
    {
        //Cleaned up for brevity...There are virtual methods and fields 
        //getting overriden but they aren't relevant to the example

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(6)]
        [Required]
        public int FieldTemplateId { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(9)]
        [Required]
        public int RowId { get; set; }
    }

    public class TextFormField:FormField
    {
        //Some overriden field / methods. 
        //None of the serialized fields are overriden
    }

    public class PersonSelectionFormField:FormField
    {
        //Some overriden field / methods. 
        //None of the serialized fields are overriden
    }   
}
```

Comment: Any chance of a minimal but complete repro so I can be sure of the exact context being discussed?

Comment: Again, happy to help, but I need more context

Comment: I updated with a sample of the C# classes and the .proto file.

Comment: Your question refers to `ButtonFormField`, which doesn't appear in the examples...? (there's no way protobuf-net would try casting to something it has never heard of)

Comment: I shortened the sample for brevity. There are actually about a dozen sub classes of form field, including buttonformfield, but I didn't think including all that boilerplate code and .proto text would be helpful.

Comment: K; I belive this is an already-logged issue relating to the order of fields. Until I can invest the time to properly fix protobuf-net for this, how do you feel about renumbering the fields? Is that an option at all? I can provide a workaround if it is...